# Can we install developer app from Xcode 7.3 to iphone 5?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7

I have mac os version 10.11 and xcode 7.3 beta. I want to test app which I am developing on iphone 5. Is it possible to install it with/without apple developer account? I am specifically using apple's 'frequent location' API and need to know if I can run that on iphone 5. Also, can I do this with latest ipad?

Answer (score 0):

You need an Apple Developer Account, it will be used to create a certificate to install the app on the phone. But is not required to get a membership from Apple Developer Program. More info here: https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/